# How can I add a margin to the header and footer? [screenshots included]

Tags: css, html, margin

How can I make my website look more like the second image presented below? (Notice the left margin in the second image, versus no margin in the first one.)

http://fotografcim-2.hosting.parking.ru/ (This is a demo site.)

No margin: 
[image: Before]

Margin:
[image: After]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div#outer {
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border:1px solid #D0D4C9;
margin:0 auto 5px;
padding:0;
width:80%;
}
```

The above one is your style

I remove the  auto in the margin:

Put margin as you want

```
margin:0 5px;
```

Use FF Firebug addon for better understanding

Refer these

http://www.webreference.com/authoring/style/sheets/layout/advanced/

http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/examples/positioning2.html

Answer (score 0):

I would surround that all in a wrapper and set the `width` of that wrapper to the current width of the internal `div`.